# Como enumerar filas en una tabla en Power BI

Tags: powerbi

Tengo una tabla la cual quisiera enumerar, crear una nueva columna y que me pueda enumerar cada uno de los registros.

Algo así como la columna del ejemplo **Index Row** como un índice que cuente cada una de las filas. Anexo imagen de ejemplo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me imagino, que la tabla ya la tienes importada en Power BI. Si este es el caso, debes ir a Power Query, mediante el botón "Transformar datos".

Una vez en Power Query, en el menú "Agregar columna" dispones de la opción "Columna de índice" y dentro de ella opciones para decidir desde que valor debe empezar esta columna.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mediante el editor avanzado también puedes conseguir el mismo resultado con código "M":

```
Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Paso anterior", "Index Row", 1, 1, Int64.Type)
```

En la sentencia anterior, a partir del paso anterior, añadimos una columna denominada "Index Row", desde el número 1, que se incrementa en 1 para cada registro y es de tipo entero.